# Can I write "or" statements in Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, cucumberjs

I am new to using the Cucumber testing framework and am trying to test if a table contains a value in one of the cells. The value I am looking for can vary between 4 different values: Pending, Idle, Active, Unknown. How can I test to see if at least one of these values exist?

This is what I have currently but it only tests for one of the values:

```
  Scenario: Status exists in my table
    When I am in the Edge UI
     And I click "Administration"
     And I click "Sites"
    Then I see "Site Elements"
     And I see "Idle" inside table
```

This is what I want to be able to do:

```
  Scenario: Status exists in my table
    When I am in the Edge UI
     And I click "Administration"
     And I click "Sites"
    Then I see "Site Elements"
     And I see "Idle" or "Pending" or "Active" or "Unknown" inside table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make regex pattern in last row like this:

And I see (.*)

After that in method you can use ifs ose switch

Switch(parameter)
{
 Case: "Idle":
   // logic here
}

Comment: You'd definitely want to account for the end of the string. _And I see (.*) inside table_ and then parse out the strings inside the quotes. Also worth looking at Regexp.exec() and matchAll().

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cucumber expressions give you the flexibility to use or's via `/`. 
See https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/#alternative-text for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your Cukes in a different way. Instead of using your cukes to document HOW you do something you should use them to document WHAT you are doing and WHY its important. This involves pushing all the HOW into step definitions or better yet helper methods called by step definitions.

The second thing you want a scenario to do is too actually test some behaviour. So ideally you want to do something that changes one of these states, i.e. you perfom an action that results in the value from pending to active.

All this stuff about clicking this and clicking that and seeing particular strings is a really good way to write really fragile scenarios which break whenever someone changes minor details in HOW something is done even if those changes don't break the functionality of what is being done

Answer (score 0):

```
Scenario: Any status exists in my table
 When I am in the Edge UI
  And I click "Administration"
  And I click "Sites"
 Then I see "Site Elements"
  And I see a site status inside the table
```

I believe this is what you are trying to communicate here. Inside your step definition, you can then check that it is one of the recognised statuses.

`Given('I see a site status inside the table', function (){...})`

However, if you're trying to locate each individual one, then splitting this into a Scenario Outline, and using some of the other answers here as inspiration, you can match the status that you are meant to see in each scenario:

```
defineParameterType(new ParameterType(
    'siteStatus',      
    /Idle|Pending|Active|Unknown/,
    String,             
    s => new String(s)
))

Given('I see "{siteStatus}" inside the table', function (){...})
```

OR

`Given(/^I see "(Idle|Pending|Active|Unknown) inside the table"$/, function (){...})`

Alongside

```
Scenario Template: Each status exists in my table
 When I am in the Edge UI
  And I click "Administration"
  And I click "Sites"
 Then I see "Site Elements"
  And I see a "<status>" inside the table

Scenarios:
 | status  |
 | Idle    |
 | Pending |
 | Active  |
 | Unknown |
```